# fullcalendar.js: dragging multiple External events

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

Im trying to drag multiple external events using the FullCalendar.io !

first im selecting the external elementes by clicking with the mouse. 
im using this:

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {       
            $(this).click(function(){
                $( this ).toggleClass("selected");
            });
```

So far so good...

Now, when i drop the object  i can find the element droped by doing:

```
...
drop: function() {
            $('.fc-event.ui-draggable.selected').each(function() 
                {
                //alert($(this).text());
                //$(this).toggleClass("selected");
                })
```

But now... how can i creat the elements dropped on the calendar for ex. with 15 minutos duration each?

Thanks

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

I did it by looping each 'clientEvents' in the draggable calendar, then I checked for the class, and added a new event to the calendar.

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) {
       $.each( $('#external-events .fc-event').fullCalendar('clientEvents'), function(index, event) {
                if( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {  
var newEvent = [{
                        title: event.innerHTML,
                        start: date,  
                        allDay: true
                    }];

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newEvent);
                    $(this).toggleClass("selected"); 
                 }
            });
```

***edit: using FullCalendar v2.2.6